# router push doesn't work in vuejs when i want to pass params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, router

When I want to use programmatic navigation by `vue-router` package it works, but when I want to pass params to a component with `router.push` methods, it doesn't work at all. Does anybody have a solution?

My code here:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes';

const router = new VueRouter({routes});

Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

and the push code:

```
router.push({ name: 'reportArchive', params: {token: token} });
```

My route config:

```
{ path: '/reportArchive', name: 'reportArchive', component: reportArchive },
```

Comment: You should also share the route config. Does your `reportArchive` route accept a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to pass param, you will need to set the route to accept param, just like below :

```
{ path: '/reportArchive/:token', name: 'reportArchive', component: reportArchive },
```

This is as per Eldar's answer above, but if you want to pass url query parameters, you need to use query instead of params in the code, for example :

```
router.push({ name: 'reportArchive', query: {token: token} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route definition doesn't accept a paramater. You should define your route as below :

```
{ path: '/reportArchive/:token', name: 'reportArchive', component: reportArchive },
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. You know, even the browser url does not change at all.

Comment: @SaeedJamali can you produce a CodeSandbox (or anything else) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I was facing the same issue as mentioned by @SaeedJamali. 
Found out why it doesn't work.

If we try to pass incorrect optional params, somehow this.$router.push breaks internally and doesn't work the subsequent attempts